# Named routes vs controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there any difference between using a named route to specifying controller and action?

```
<%= link_to 'link', controller: :users, action: :index %>
```

Will give the same result as

```
<%= link_to 'link', users_path %>
```

What I would like to know is if there's any difference, or which one is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer `users_path`. There is functionally no difference, but the helper methods let you change the controller/action which handles a particular action without changing every link that leads to the action.

It's also shorter while not compromising on readability. In fact, there is a shorter version that I personally prefer:

```
<%= link_to 'link', :users %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no difference whatsoever as long as `users_path` routes to `users#index`. Though `users_path` may be preferable to most for the sake of brevity. It also is more readable when passing params to the route: `users_path(search: 'John')`